# 2 consiquenced presign post urls to S3 with boto3

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto3

I`m trying to generate 2 consequence pressing post urls for posting to S3 using boto3. This urls I return to user to post 2 semantically connected files that have different format.

```
full_ecs_xsd_key = 'txn/jackalope/edispec/TPD/local/opikovets/my_test_file_3'

fields = {
    "x-amz-meta-identity-id": user_id,
    "x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
}
conditions = [
    {"x-amz-meta-identity-id": user_id},
    {"x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"}
]

xsd_key = full_ecs_xsd_key + '.xsd'
pre_signed_xsd_post_url = copy.deepcopy(s3_client.generate_presigned_post(
    bucket_name, xsd_key,
    Fields=fields,
    Conditions=conditions
))

ecs_key = full_ecs_xsd_key + '.ecs'
pre_signed_ecs_post_url = copy.deepcopy(s3_client.generate_presigned_post(
    bucket_name, ecs_key,
    Fields=fields,
    Conditions=conditions
))
```

as a result, I get 2 urls which seems to be working, but I`m not able to post data to the second url (pre_signed_ecs_post_url). Getting an error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "$key", "txn/jackalope/edispec/TPD/local/opikovets/my_test_file_3.xsd"]</Message>
    <RequestId>1343F7E406E82C1A</RequestId>
    <HostId>wm0U14OouoMkbm0bWIqkYDtP7fgR2A+0Q/Mvhvo9sJ7paaXDiMWfqnjCMR4mc5euPcXCyP3u2/w=</HostId>
</Error>
```

What is confusing here is that key, displayed in the error is actually a key for the first url, not the second one. So, I think that when I call generate_presigned_post for the first time it creates an instance of a class that is also used for creating second url...

But that`s only a guess, and I have no idea how to solve this particular problem

Comment: What's in the "fields" and "contents?"

Comment: Thanks.  Now, dump the contents of fields and conditions immediately before the line that says `ecs_key = full_ecs_xsd_key + '.ecs'`.  What do they look like?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot added

Comment: Well, I see that you edited the question, and have switched from using 2 different client objects to one,  but what I'm looking for is printing the actual content of the `fields` and `conditions` structures at the point of execution.  I'm speculating that the contents may be changing as a result of calling `generate_presigned_post()`.

Comment: Thank you for that! That is actually what was wrong... When I switched to send copy of `fields` and `conditions` to the `generate_presigned_post()` the issue is gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @Michael-sqlbot comments, `fields` and `conditions` are changing during the `generate_presigned_post()` execution, so I`ve changed the call to:

```
ecs_key = full_ecs_xsd_key + '.ecs'
pre_signed_ecs_post_url = s3_client.generate_presigned_post(
    bucket_name, ecs_key,
    Fields=copy.deepcopy(fields),
    Conditions=copy.deepcopy(conditions)
)

xsd_key = full_ecs_xsd_key + '.xsd'
pre_signed_xsd_post_url = s3_client.generate_presigned_post(
    bucket_name, xsd_key,
    Fields=copy.deepcopy(fields),
    Conditions=copy.deepcopy(conditions)
)
```

and everything worked just fine